If the image of the canonical injection is closed, the space is complete

Let $E$ a normed space and $j: E \rightarrow E'', j(x)=\hat x$ where $\hat x : E' \rightarrow \Bbb{K}, \hat x(f)=f(x)$ . Then, $E$ is complete iff $j(E)$ is closed on $E''$ .

I am trying to prove this in order to use it on another proof, but I am struggling with it. The first part is easy since, if $E$ is complete $j(E)$ is also complete by continuity of $j$, so it is a Banach subspace of a normed space, and thus $j(E)$ is closed.
For the second part, I have tried to take a Cauchy sequence $(x_n) \subset E$ and someway use the Banach-Steinhaus Theorem with $(\hat x_n) \subset j(E)$ in order to prove that there converges and so $(x_n)$ converges on $E$, but I am not reaching anything, so any possible help would be appreciated.

It's entirely possible for the image of a Banach space by a continuous linear injection not to be closed, see for instance the map $T:L^2[0,1]\to L^1[0,1]$, $T(f)=f$. What you need is the fact that $j$ is an isometry. For the "if" part, $E''$ is the dual of some space, therefore it's a Banach space and its closed subspaces are Banach spaces. Since $j$ is an isometry, $E$ is Banach too.

If $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $E$, then by continuity of $j$ we get that $(j(x_n))$ is Cauchy in $j(E)$. However, if $j(E)$ is closed in in $E''$, then $j(E)$ is complete (as $E''$ is complete). Thus, there exists $y\in j(E)$ such that $j(x_n) \rightarrow j(y)$. In particular we have $j(x_n-y) \rightarrow 0$. However, $j$ is an isometry and hence $x_n-y\rightarrow 0$.

@SassatelliGiulio Thanks for the correction, my mistake

@SeverinSchraven thanks for your comment!
